# Why does my session info get cleared when clearing history?

Tags: codeigniter, session-variables, browser-cache, browser-history

I'm using CodeIgniter and I set my sessions like this example:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('psLoggedInUser', $UserN );
```

During development I want to clear chache (for example), and run 'clean'. But I want to preseve my logged-in sessions. For example, I also have gmail and linkedin on other tabs and I don't want to be logged out.

However, the moment I clear browser history making sure that log-in sessions aren't cleared, I find myself out of my development site. But I remain logged into gmail.

Why is this happening? Does it mean that gmail uses a different mechanism to keep track of logged in sessions?

Comment: Hi itsols, Did you get its answer?  bcs i also stuck somewhere same situation ( in my recent question it is ).

Comment: Nope. I'm afraid I didn't. In fact I didn't even look at this issue since it's been a while. But if you do find an answer, please let me know or post your answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a difference between Cookie and cache, 
   Cache clears only image files and downloaded data but not cookies, Your session will always save in cookie part

For ex. When you want to clear browser cache from chrome with alt+ctrl+del there you can see multiple options,  for cache its different option to select and for cookie its different

2. For concept of Gmail pelease select below link:

https://superuser.com/questions/462973/how-can-i-stop-gmail-from-keeping-me-logged-in-after-i-close-the-browser

Hope It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can override or Set a Config
Item dynamically . If you simply look
at
    `$config
['sess_expire_on_close'] =
TRUE;`
  Whether to make the session
to expire automatically when the
browser window is closed.
Set it to true if user did not check
the remember me checkbox. And the
session will expire after user close
the browser.
And if he checks the remember me
checkbox, set
     `$config
['sess_expire_on_close'] 
 to FALSE`
like

```
`if($this->input->post('remember')) $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close','0'); //'` 
 remember is
```

checkbox name.
now session will not expire after
browser is closed. note: this solution
is also tested on Opera, Mozilla,
Chrome and ie9

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think there's a small misunderstanding. Let me clarify... When I close the window and come back, my session is active. However, when I clear the browser's cache, my gmail session remains but my site's session is lost. That's my concern :/